How can I see the HTML code that is generated from bslib?
In R, if I for example print pickerInput I can see the HTML code that is generated. But when If try doing this with functions from bslib, then it shows the output in the viewer. How can I see the HTML code that is generated by for example accordion, accordion_panel, card etc., directly in RStudio without opening developer tools in Chrome. The reason is that I want to make some custom changes to the HTML code.

One way is to wrap it in a tag, for example div(accordion()), div(accordion(accordion_panel(title = "testing"))
